# How to find the L3 Cache parameters on Intel CPUs?

Tags: linux, caching, memory, cpu

I would like to know the following L3 cache parameters. But not sure how to get them, I also pasted the /proc/cpuinfo output (4 processors, only pasted the first one, the others are repetitive.)

CACHE_SIZE

LINE_SIZE

Associativity

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 58
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz
stepping    : 9
microcode   : 0x15
cpu MHz     : 1200.000
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
bogomips    : 5786.68
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

UPDATE 1: It seems that someone posted the cache size and associativity here:
http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Core_i7/Intel-Core%20i7-3520M%20%28PGA%29%20Mobile%20processor.html

But still I dont know the line size.

Comment: Why do you ask? You could use the `hwinfo` command. Cache line is generally 32 bytes.

Comment: is this standard linux command? I cannot find it in my ubuntu 14.04 system.

Comment: Do `sudo aptitude install hwinfo`

Comment: It only tells L3 cache size. I dont see more information using this utility compared to /proc/cpuinfo.

Answer (score 2):

Hwloc / lstopo

Hwloc (Portable hardware locality) is a small utility that reports the structure of the processor in a neat visual diagram. The diagram shows the number of cores, hyperthreads and cache size. A single diagram tells it all.

```
   $ sudo apt-get install hwloc
   $ hwloc
```

Comment: I cannot see my line size and associativity in the output. Could you elaborate a bit?